# Problems with display image byte() on image tag

Tags: asp.net, database, image, drag-and-drop, xmlhttprequest

I'm try to show images from database in a client side, but, I have been using many kinds of examples that I found and none work, none of the images shown. The last example I saw it's this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/445876/Auto-bind-byte-to-asp-Image

I understand perfectly the example, but the images are still not displayed.

Someone help me a bit with this issue?

In summary, I'm use a HTML5 drag & drop files. Send the files via XMLHttpRequest in a FormData object. One handler take this files in byte() and store in SQL DataBase.

**Client code:**

```
$("#btnUploadFile").click(function () {
    if (files.length <= 0) {
        alert("Debe seleccionar algún fichero para subirlo.");
    } else {
        var expID = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hfExpId").val();
        var formData = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            alert(files[i].name);
            formData.append('file', files[i]);
        }
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', "FileHandler.ashx", true);
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined-binary');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("ExpedienteID", expID);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                RefreshFilePanel();
            } else {
                console.log('Something went terribly wrong...');
            }
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
    };
```

**Handle code:**

```
    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim documentBytes As Byte()
    Dim lExpId As String = context.Request.Headers("ExpedienteID")
    Dim fLenght As Integer

    If (context.Request.Files.Count > 0) Then
        Dim files As HttpFileCollection = context.Request.Files

        For i = 0 To files.Count - 1
            fLenght = files(i).ContentLength
            documentBytes = New Byte(fLenght - 1) {}
            context.Request.InputStream.Read(documentBytes, 0, fLenght)
            UploadDocumentBy_ExpID(documentBytes, files(i).FileName, "Description" & lExpId.ToString, lExpId)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

More late, I try to put this byte() in a image tag on grid.

**aspx code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDocumentoByExp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="250px" DataSourceID="dtsDocumentByExpId">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Archivo" HeaderText="Archivo" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="docId" HeaderText="docId" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Documento" HeaderText="Documento" Visible="false" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Image 
               ID="imgThumb" 
               runat="server"
               ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(Eval("Documento")) %>'
               />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

**And the function GetImage in codebehind:**

```
    Public Function GetImage(image As Object) As String
    Return "data:image/gif;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(DirectCast(image, [Byte]()))
End Function
```

In all steps, there is no error, but I think that the error is posible located in the byte() file format..but i'm not sure.

Someone help me?

Sorry for my inglish and Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you read the file:

```
context.Request.InputStream.Read(documentBytes, 0, fLenght)
```

The `Read` method returns the number of bytes read, which can be less than the number of bytes that you request. You have to loop until you have got all bytes:

```
Dim offset as Integer = 0
Dim len as Integer
Do While offset < fLength
  len = context.Request.InputStream.Read(documentBytes, offset, fLenght - offset)
  offset += len
Loop
```

Comment: @AMGHoshi: Is it a GIF image? What does the final src look like?